# counting order pairs (A,B)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following counting problem and came up till this far.

How many ordered pairs (A,B) are there where A and B are subsets of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and

[1] have $A \cap B = \phi$

[2] have $A \cap B$ = {1}

[3] have $|A \cap B|$ = 1

Here is how I progressed for [1].

I assume at any point in time set A consists on m elements. Number of ways I can choose m elements from 5 elements is: ${5 \choose m}$.

Since the intersection of A & B doesn't have any elements in common, so set B has to be built using zero or more from the remaining (5 - m) elements.

Number of such set B = |P(B)| = $2^{5 - m}$

Total number of such pairs = $\sum_{m=0}^{5} {5 \choose m}*2^{5 - m}$ = 243

For [2] my thought process is as follows:
Set A & B has `1` in common. A = {1, ...another m - 1 elements} if A has total of m elements. B = {1, another (4 - m) elements disjoint from m elements in A}. Using the logic from [1]

Total number such pairs = $\sum_{m=1}^{4} {4 \choose (m - 1)}*2^{5 - m}$ = 81

For [3]: A & B needs to have at least one element each. So if A has m elements then $1 \le m \le 5$
When A has m elements, then B will have (6 - m) elements as they have one element in common.

Number of ways to make A = ${5 \choose m}$

For each of them |P(B)| = $2^{6 - m}$

Each of the terms of the product ${5 \choose m} * 2^{6 - m}$ needs to be multiplied by `m` as there are `m` choices of the common element between A & B

Total count = $\sum_{m=1}^{5} {5 \choose m}*2^{6 - m}*m$ = 810

Is my thought process correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(1)** Your argument is correct. Your answer of $243$ is just $3^5$ and that suggests a nice way of getting the answer more easily:

Each element can either be in A or in B or in neither. So the number of possibilities is $3\times 3\times ... \times 3=3^5.$

**(2)** As you correctly point out the same argument can be used and your answer of $81$ is again correct. But note the comment by @layabout.

**(3)** Here the argument is not correct. We have $81$ possibilities for each of $5$ numbers and so the answer is $405$.

Comment: Unless I'm making some mistake, isn't $\sum_{m=1}^{4} {4 \choose (m - 1)}2^{5 - m} = 80$, rather than $81$. I think the correct summation for 2) is $\sum_{m=1}^{5} {4 \choose (m - 1)}2^{5 - m}=81$.

Comment: @layabout. Yes thanks - I've noted this to the OP now.